# How to compress stdout without block buffering

Tags: bash, pipe, compression

I tryed this

```
myprogram | gzip > /var/log/mylog.log
```

In my understanding this will write to log file only when a whole gzip block is produced, which I think is 32kB. This introduces considerable lag in writing to disk. If system crashes the last portion of the log would be lost.

Is there any alternative to gzip that compress and write bytes as soon as they arrive? I think there are some compression algorithms that are not based on blocks, but rather on stream of byte, but I am not able to find if such tool exist.

Comment: Apart from waiting for the completion of blocks, Linux-type systems cache output data in RAM so the process does not need to wait for the device to complete the transfers. The cache can be "synchronised" with the device, but doing that frequently can be a serious performance hit. Some smarter devices (like SSD) have internal device caching too. Having your own process crash is far more likely than having the whole system crash (in production systems).

Comment: Have you considered using a filesystem that supports transparent compression?  e.g. ZFS or btrfs.   With transparent compression, the only time you actually need to compress a file is when it is huge AND you need to transfer it to another system.  For local-use-only files, just set the compression type on the dataset and forget about it.  It costs a tiny, negligible amount of CPU power but gains you effectively more disk space and disk performance (it's generally much faster to read and decompress fewer blocks than to read more uncompressed blocks)

Answer (score 4):

> In my understanding this will write to log file only when a whole gzip block is produced, which I think is 32kB.

Well, the job of a compressor is to take many bits and make fewer bits of these. Hence, some block-wise operation is basically inherent – in the end, anything Lempel-Ziv-similar (like gzip, but also like many, even most, other compressors out there) has the job of finding symbols in a code book, and you can't know if a symbol has been found until the match to your code book has been completed.

That paired with a periodic reset of the codebook leads to relatively fixed block lengths. (As in: gzip can't let you choose the block size. The block size picking is inherent to gzip's compression method.)

- You could use something slightly less archaic than `gzip`; maybe `xz`'s `--flush-timeout` is what you're actually looking for.
- If 32 kB seems to be "much logs", then maybe you don't need to compress at all? In fact, mechanisms like logrotate go exactly that route: switch over to a new log every so and so many megabytes (not much data for a modern computer), and only compress the old files.
- Also, your average file system  and block device layer buffer is much larger than 32 kB. You need to have your file system in fsync mount mode, and mustn't forget that even so, a physical block of your storage device is probably 4 kB (or a multiple); doing much smaller writes has serious performance implications, if it is actually always flushed to the storage medium.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions, most of which require that you write your own compression tool (that you set to write out more often - the Lempel-Ziv based ones can write a stream, but are limited to only write full bytes, and LZ streams usually have varying bit length tokens, so things are not on 8 bit boundaries, but it could still write out, at any time, everything, that it has compressed, except for the portion at the end that is a partial byte still).  This however is a rather painful way to do it.

A much simpler method, but it requires 2 "pieces" would be:

```bash
myprogram | split -u -l 1M -d /var/log/myprogram.log
```

This will create a series of log files, always up to date, never larger than 1 MB.

Then, you can have program that watches for a new log file to no longer be open, and then compresses it, and then deletes it.

The latest log information will always be immediately available, and the log files will never be larger than 1 MB.  gzip will always finish compressing the "old" file(s) before removing them, so you will never lose any log information.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  for file in /var/log/myprogram.log*[^z]; do
    proc_count=$(lsof -t "$file" | wc -l)
    if (( $proc_count == 0 )); then
      gzip "$file"
    fi
  done
  sleep 1
done
```

The best solution would be a program that does both things; which I may write, as I found your post because I want the same thing.